# How to create a list of users on in Alfresco Activiti?

Tags: forms, alfresco, activiti, bpmn

so I have this simple question that I would love to get anwserd. 
I am new to BPM an Alfresco Activiti and I am workng on with the trial version of Alfresco Activiti to create a sample project for our company.
I decided to work with the Step editor to se what it can do and if it's as powerfull as a normal BPMN 2.0 editor.
Now I am working on a form where one user would need to select the user for the next task. I was wondering if it's possible to use the single select component to display all the users on the server from which the asignee for the next task could be selected. How can this be done?
I know it is not the bes pracitce to show all the users on the server but this is a test project and your help would be really appreciated.

If any more info is required I will gladly edit the post.

Thnak you.

Answer (score 2):

There is a user picker form control in there, that allows searching the whole system. See the third entry:

[image]

Comment: Any chance you could edit your answer to include a screenshot / documentation reference / etc, to help people find the right control they should use?

Comment: Sure, added screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a dropdown whose options are populated from a rest call which is provided below.

```
GET api/enterprise/admin/users
```

This will return list of all users available in JSON format.

Hope it helped.